# Calculus Inequalities

Tags: calculus

Using the fact that $(1+x)^{0.5}$ < $1 + 0.5x$ $\forall x > 0$ , prove that $(1+x)^{0.5}$ > $1 + 0.5x$ - $0.125x^2$  $\forall x > 0$.

My method of doing is : I bring the -$0.125x^2$ to the left, i get $(1+x)^{0.5}$ + $0.125x^2$ > $1 + 0.5x$ , which is indeed true, since the derivative of $(1+x)^{0.5}$ + $0.125x^2$ > derivative of $1 + 0.5x$ $\forall$ $x >0$. Therefore, i conclude that $(1+x)^{0.5}$ + $0.125x^2>1 + 0.5x \implies (1+x)^{0.5} > 1 + 0.5x - 0.125x^2$  $\forall x > 0$ since we are given that $(1+x)^{0.5} < 1 + 0.5x$ $\forall x > 0$ and the derivative of $(1+x)^{0.5}$ $<$ derivative of $1 + 0.5x$ when  $x > 0$

Am i correct to show it through the derivative? I have seen the graph of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is almost correct. It is a great idea to use derivatives to prove this inequality. There is only one thing you have to add to your proof: You have to compare the two expressions at the beginning of the support (which is 0 in this case).

So, because $(1 + 0)^{0.5} = 1$ and $1 + 0.5 \cdot 0 -0.125 \cdot 0 ^{0.5}= 1$, there is an equality of the two expressions for $x=0$. But you want to prove it just for $x > 0$ and you proved (by using derivatives) that the first expression increases faster than the second one for all $x>0$, thus the first expression is greater for all $x>0$ and the proof is completed.

Answer (score 0):

for $x>2+2\sqrt{3}$ is your inequality fulfilled, since $1+\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{8}x^2$ is negative and $\sqrt{x+1}$ is positive. For $x\le 2+2\sqrt{3}$ you can square your inequality